# Careers - can you add UK counties?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, jobs, location, employers

When adding a careers advert can you add UK counties?

"Berkshire, UK" would yield better results than just "Reading, UK".

Comment: actually the same would probably be true in the US too.

Comment: I should think Jon Skeet has the Reading and Berkshire job markets sewn up though - in spare moments between posts to SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>We use a yahoo api to standardize locations and have no control over that. While it seems that it does understand US states, UK counties are rounded up England, United Kingdom (Welsh counties are rounded up to Wales, United Kingdom; Scottish counties otoh are displayed as [county name], Scotland, United Kingdom...).</strike>

Should we ever decide to use another solution this behavior may change.

**update**

As digiguru pointed out counties can be had through yahoo. Turns out we don't allow them (Scotland notwithstanding) - my bad.

Job listings should be tied to a single location, as that's where the job is at. Depending on the search radius chosen by job seekers the job will be found, and we are already determining job listings shown on Stack Overflow based on area rather than location. The relevant people will still find the job when the location is a city, and it will provide more information to the candidates as to where they will be working.

Comment: I beg to differ.... http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/24554868/children?appid=[your app id here]